# Youtube embedded link not working in mobile app

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-webview, webviewclient

There is 1 module in website where we add `YouTube` embed link.
In website used `<iframe src="embed_url"></iframe>` and its working.

> Working video link (https://www.youtube.com/embed/XG9U7nJv0aE)
>
> Not working video link (https://www.youtube.com/embed/9ClYy0MxsU0)

In mobile apps (Android/iOS), facing issue while playing video in apps. It shows Video unavailable.

> for android playing video using `webview`

```
wv_webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser(pb_insidewv_webView));
wv_webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
wv_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv_webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
wv_webView.loadUrl(loadVideo);
```

> class

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public MyBrowser(ProgressBar pb_insidewv_webView) {
        this.progressBar = pb_insidewv_webView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        pb_insidewv_webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPageFinished: 553->" + url);
        pb_insidewv_webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        pb_insidewv_webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceivedError: 558->" + description);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you given INTERNET permission ?

Comment: yes, that why i am getting embed url from API

Comment: did you add your manifest this android:hardwareAccelerated="true" inside application

Comment: use youtube player library instead of webview in android

Comment: @NalanUlusoy yes i added this.

Comment: @VivekMishra youtube library will not work in case of server url